# Why does this use of reflection invocation cause a StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm learning about reflection in Java and i have a little problem - I would like to invoke two methods - First I would like to set the location of my jframe and in the second one add buttons to it.

But unfortunately in both my methods I receive `StackOverflowError` and it looks like my method invoke was invoked more than once...

I read some faq and tutorials on how to use invoke methods but I am doing something wrong...

Could anybody help me please?

```
public class zad2 extends JFrame{

public int setLocationtest(int x, int y){

    setLocation(x,y);
    return 1;
}
public void addButton(String txt){

    add(new JButton("Przycisk 1"+txt));

}


    zad2() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        super("tytuł");
        getContentPane().setLayout (new GridLayout(2,2));
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocation(350,50);



        Method testMethod = zad2.class.getDeclaredMethod("setLocationtest", Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
        testMethod.setAccessible(true);
        testMethod.invoke(new zad2(), 10, 10);
        //setLocationtest(20,50);

        Method testMethodbt = zad2.class.getDeclaredMethod("addButton", String.class);

        testMethodbt.invoke(new zad2(), "1");

        setVisible(true);       

    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    new zad2();

}
```

}

Comment: `testMethodbt.invoke(new zad2(), "1");` in the constructor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor `zad2` is creating another instance of `zad2` here:

```
testMethodbt.invoke(new zad2(), "1");
```

That will call the same constructor on another instance, which will create its own `new zad2()`, and so on, and this will continue until the stack overflows.

If you meant to invoke the method on the current instance, pass `this` instead of a new `zad2`.

This applies also to the earlier line in the constructor:

```
testMethod.invoke(new zad2(), 10, 10);
```

Of course it raises the question of why reflection is needed, when a straight method call would suffice here.

Answer (score 1):

```
zad2() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    // blah blah . . .
    testMethod.invoke(new zad2(), 10, 10);
```

see the recursion? `new zad2()` -> `new zad2()` -> `new zad2()` . . .

Try using `this` instead.